# Concatenate Dataframe rows based on timestamp value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Dataframe with text messages and a timestamp value for each row.
Like so:

```
+--------------------------+---------------------+
| message                  | timestamp           |
+--------------------------+---------------------+
| some text from message 1 | 2019-08-03 01:00:00 |
+--------------------------+---------------------+
| some text from message 2 | 2019-08-03 01:01:00 |
+--------------------------+---------------------+
| some text from message 3 | 2019-08-03 01:03:00 |
+--------------------------+---------------------+
```

I need to concatenate the messages by creating time windows of X number of minutes so that for example they look like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| message                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| some text from message 1 some text from message 2 |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| some text from message 3                          |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

After doing the concatenation I have no use for the timestamp column so I can drop it or keep it with any value.

I have been able to do this by iterating through the entire Dataframe, adding timestamp diffs and inserting into a new Dataframe when the time window is achieved. It works but it's ugly and I am looking for some pointers into how to accomplish this in Scala in a more functional/elegant way.

I looked at the Window functions but since I am not doing aggregations it appears that I do not have a way to access the content of the groups once the WindowSpec is created so I didn't get very far.

I also looked at the lead and lag functions but I couldn't figure out how to use them without also having to go into a for loop.

I appreciate any ideas or pointers you can provide.

Any thoughts or pointers into how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`window` datetime function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@window(timeColumn:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,windowDuration:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) (not to be confused with [`Window`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window) functions) to generate time windows, followed by a `groupBy` to aggregate messages using `concat_ws`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("message1", "2019-08-03 01:00:00"),
  ("message2", "2019-08-03 01:01:00"),
  ("message3", "2019-08-03 01:03:00")
).toDF("message", "timestamp")

val duration = "2 minutes"

df.
  groupBy(window($"timestamp", duration)).
  agg(concat_ws(" ", collect_list($"message")).as("message")).
  show(false)
// +------------------------------------------+-----------------+
// |window                                    |message          |
// +------------------------------------------+-----------------+
// |[2019-08-03 01:00:00, 2019-08-03 01:02:00]|message1 message2|
// |[2019-08-03 01:02:00, 2019-08-03 01:04:00]|message3         |
// +------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! this seems to be what I was looking for